# Best practice to make use of Client Secret Key in SaaS environment

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

The **Asp.NET Web API** generates a **Secret Key** (*using Symmetric Algorithm 32 characters long*)  when a brand new client gets registered which is stored in a database column (*has unique constraint on it*). Throughout, the API usage a client must provide the **Secret Key** in an Authorization header in order to access the it's own resources (*Multi-Tenant SaaS environment*). There is no requirement for Access Token at the moment. The main reason of expecting Client Secret Key is to filter and deliver an appropriate data from the database!

I think fetching Client Data from SQL Table using the ClientSecretKey in a WHERE clause is not going to be performance friendly, for an example:

*`SELECT Multiple_Columns from ClientTable WHERE ClientSecretKey='X3i1aBer'`*

Ideally, I would prefer to fetch the client records using ClientId which is defined as an **IDENTITY** column in a table.

**Questions:**

1. How best to design a Unique Client Key that should be absolutely performance friendly when executing the query against database to fetch that specific client records?
2. Is there any flaw in my thinking or the design?

Any ideas would be REALLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client should likely be passing in an ID and the secret key.  Think of these as a username and password.  This greatly reduces the chance of abuse by someone just throwing a bunch of characters at the API.

Both the ID and the secret key column should be indexed in the database to avoid performance issues.

For simple string keys like this, it is my personal preference that the database not give me any results back if the key does not match.  That way, I do not have to worry about some security leak sending that back to the client.

So, yes, the key should be in the where clause, but it should not be the only thing in the where clause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have thought about instructing the clients to pass the ClientId (Integer) but am not sure what would be the format? Is it going to be a separate the Authorization Key?

Comment: There should only ever be 1 authorization header, but you could put them both in the auth header and parse them out.

Comment: I was thinking to propose consumers to concatenate Client Id along with Secret Key in some sort of fixed format. The secret key will be retrieved from database table using 'ClientId' in WHERE clause and Secret Key gets validated with what Consumer sends using String Compare. Hope, it makes sense? :)